# How to prevent IDEA from wrapping long URLs in comments?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting

I've got a one line comment in a Java method:

```
// See https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#signed-trade-and-user_data-endpoint-security
```

IDEA wraps this line into:

```
// See https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api
// .md#signed-trade-and-user_data-endpoint-security
```

thus breaking the URL. I suspect it is being thrown off by the dot in the URL.

**How do I configure the IDE not to line-wrap in this case?**

**UPDATE**: I filed https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189817 because I believe this is a bug.

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004520/code-wrap-intellij) and [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813662/eclipse-like-comment-formatting-in-intellij-idea) might help you.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri Thank you for trying to help but the links you provided only help if I can find a way to prevent wrapping to begin with.

Comment: As of IntelliJ 2020.2, the trick is to put the URL or the `<a href="...">` on its own line. The line won't wrap (at least, from what I just tried). But if you have a leading "See" on the same line, it will wrap mid-URL due to the length. So my advice is to try to isolate the URL or `<a href="...">` to its own line. Note that the text in the `a` and the closing `</a>` can be on following lines. It's just the opening `<a>` tag that seems to need to be completely on the same line to avoid wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you have the `Soft Wraps` option selected? If it is, try to deselect it.

[image]

Comment: No, that's not the case. It seems to be a legitimate bug.